# commutation of translation and homothety

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations

Under which hypothesis a translation  is commutative with  a homothety and why? my professor told me there is one case under which this works but I didn't find out. I have also tried with a figure but excluding the case of a translation with a null vector nothing

Answer (score 1):

When the homothetic center is at infinity.

Comment: ok so there are only trivial cases like what you said and translation of a null vector?